# How to get the sequence number for an account id?

Tags: transactions, accounts, sequence-number

In the below code, I explicitly gave the sequence number. How can I get the sequence number by giving the public key? Is there a way to get the sequence number of an account?

```
var StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk');
StellarSdk.Network.useTestNetwork();
var an_account = new StellarSdk.Account("GCEZWKCA5VLDNRLN3RPRJMRZOX3Z6G5CHCGSNFHEYVXM3XOJMDS674JZ", 46316927324160);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk');
var server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org'); 
server.loadAccount("GBFXHIQPYKUE7WPIACEVBIR3TRFKSYVO3LNGMQCZWNQQGRGPPGKOV7UD")
  .then(function(account) { console.log(account.sequence) })
```

Returns:

```
33845557768224768
```

---

Also try:

```
server.loadAccount("GBFXHIQPYKUE7WPIACEVBIR3TRFKSYVO3LNGMQCZWNQQGRGPPGKOV7UD")
  .then(function(account) { console.log(account) })
```

Response looks like:

```
AccountResponse {
  _baseAccount:
   Account {
     _accountId: 'GBFXHIQPYKUE7WPIACEVBIR3TRFKSYVO3LNGMQCZWNQQGRGPPGKOV7UD',
     sequence: BigNumber { s: 1, e: 16, c: [Array] } },
  _links:
   { self:
      { href: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GBFXHIQPYKUE7WPIACEVBIR3TRFKSYVO3LNGMQCZWNQQGRGPPGKOV7UD' },
     transactions:
      { href: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GBFXHIQPYKUE7WPIACEVBIR3TRFKSYVO3LNGMQCZWNQQGRGPPGKOV7UD/transactions{?cursor,limit,order}',
        templated: true },
     operations:
      { href: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GBFXHIQPYKUE7WPIACEVBIR3TRFKSYVO3LNGMQCZWNQQGRGPPGKOV7UD/operations{?cursor,limit,order}',
        templated: true },
     payments:
      { href: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GBFXHIQPYKUE7WPIACEVBIR3TRFKSYVO3LNGMQCZWNQQGRGPPGKOV7UD/payments{?cursor,limit,order}',
        templated: true },
     effects:
      { href: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GBFXHIQPYKUE7WPIACEVBIR3TRFKSYVO3LNGMQCZWNQQGRGPPGKOV7UD/effects{?cursor,limit,order}',
        templated: true },
     offers:
      { href: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GBFXHIQPYKUE7WPIACEVBIR3TRFKSYVO3LNGMQCZWNQQGRGPPGKOV7UD/offers{?cursor,limit,order}',
        templated: true },
     trades:
      { href: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GBFXHIQPYKUE7WPIACEVBIR3TRFKSYVO3LNGMQCZWNQQGRGPPGKOV7UD/trades{?cursor,limit,order}',
        templated: true },
     data:
      { href: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GBFXHIQPYKUE7WPIACEVBIR3TRFKSYVO3LNGMQCZWNQQGRGPPGKOV7UD/data/{key}',
        templated: true } },
  id: 'GBFXHIQPYKUE7WPIACEVBIR3TRFKSYVO3LNGMQCZWNQQGRGPPGKOV7UD',
  paging_token: '',
  account_id: 'GBFXHIQPYKUE7WPIACEVBIR3TRFKSYVO3LNGMQCZWNQQGRGPPGKOV7UD',
  sequence: '33845557768224768',
  subentry_count: 0,
  thresholds: { low_threshold: 0, med_threshold: 0, high_threshold: 0 },
  flags: { auth_required: false, auth_revocable: false },
  balances: [ { balance: '10000.0000000', asset_type: 'native' } ],
  signers:
   [ { public_key: 'GBFXHIQPYKUE7WPIACEVBIR3TRFKSYVO3LNGMQCZWNQQGRGPPGKOV7UD',
       weight: 1,
       key: 'GBFXHIQPYKUE7WPIACEVBIR3TRFKSYVO3LNGMQCZWNQQGRGPPGKOV7UD',
       type: 'ed25519_public_key' } ],
  data: [Function],
  self: [Function],
  transactions: [Function],
  operations: [Function],
  payments: [Function],
  effects: [Function],
  offers: [Function],
  trades: [Function],
  data_attr: {} }
```

Comment: Hello @cesar. I am trying with snippet you provided but I am getting 'undefined' as an output.

Comment: Oh sorry I made a type "seqeunce"...

var server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org');
server.loadAccount("GBFXHIQPYKUE7WPIACEVBIR3TRFKSYVO3LNGMQCZWNQQGRGPPGKOV7UD")
  .then(function(account) { console.log(account.sequence) })

Comment: var StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk');
'var server = new StellarSdk.Server('horizon-testnet.stellar.org');
server.loadAccount("GD2HPONSMOTEJQUE2WIUBPMWZ7WPAE7EBLW2RRD2XH6CIJHKCZKAYMZ3")
.then(function(account) { console.log(account.seqeunce) })'

Thorwing an error that cannot connect to insecure horizon server

Comment: Hey @cesar. It is giving an error still. 
throw new Error("Cannot connect to insecure horizon server"); I used the same code..

Comment: Perfect. It is working. Thanks a lot. Do you have any idea on multisig accounts? I am looking for that. If possible , any help

Comment: @merklexy What exactly you'd like to know? The coding or the concept behind??

Comment: @cesar...Could you check this link please. I posted the error also.
'https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/689/error-in-submitting-the-multisig-transaction'